# Shrinking and extending disks on Server while running?

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v, vhd, diskmanagement, shrink

So I have a server with Hyper-V and a Drive C: (OS) and D. 
Drive D stores all of the VHDs that I run. Drive C shows up as Disk 0, and D as Disk 1 under Disk Management respectively. Now Drive D gets low on space because the VHDs got bigger, and I need to increase the disk size since the VHDs turn off when the space gets too low. My question: Could I just go ahead and shrink C: by 50gb, and then simply extend Drive D with that? Can I simply do this while the server is running with the VHDs? I don't want to have any downtime.

Comment: The better plan would be to add sufficient storage for your virtual machines.

Comment: no the vhd's have enough space, the folder they are stored in runs low on space, since the VHDs got bigger. so when that happens, the VHDs turn off one by one.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. What I mean is that you should add additional storage **FOR** your virtual machines, not **TO** your virtual machines. I mean move them from the D drive to a larger storage disk or array.

Comment: yes, for now though, can i do that i suggested? do you know if i can do that while the VHDs are running? thank you!

Comment: It sounds like you've got your C: volume's partition taking up all of disk 0 and D: volume's partition taking up all of disk 1. There's nothing I can think of that you can do on Server 2008 that won't require any downtime. You could shrink the C: volume's partition without a reboot, maybe, and then convert the disks to dynamic disks, reboot, then make D: span across the two disks, but, well, this is a truly terrible solution. Please don't do it. joeqwerty is right here, you should either expand the size of disk1/drive D or move the VHDs to another, larger, storage solution.

Comment: i got some 100gb on C i can use and shrink C with that. the disks are not dynamic since when i right click on them it gives me the option to "Convery to dynamic disk". so i would have downtime, since they're not dynamic I can't just shrink C and extend D without downtime, correct?

Comment: Wait...are these just partitions off the same disk? If they are, you couldn't do this anyway since you can only extend to the right of the disk (at least, in Windows). You can't simply "borrow" space from another drive unless you get into the mucky areas around NTFS junctions which you should avoid.

Comment: no, no partitions. it's disk 0 which has two partitions: system reserve and C. Then disk 1 with only one partition. i want to take space from disk 0 and add it to disk 1 and wanted to know if could do that while server is running with the VHDs.